# Jupyter nbconvert function with multiple metadata masks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

**Problem**

I'm trying to clear *all* output and *almost all* metadata from a jupyter notebook. When I run the following command,

```
jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True \
--ClearMetadataPreprocessor.enabled=True \
--ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask="{('language_info', 'name'), 'kernelspec'}" \
--to=notebook --log-level=ERROR my_notebook.ipynb
```

I get the output I want,

```
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "my-kernel",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "my-kernel"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "name": "python"
  }
 }
```

but also get this warning:

```
/usr/local/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:2935: FutureWarning: --ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask={('language_info', 'name'), 'kernelspec'} for containers is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can pass `--ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask item` ... multiple times to add items to a list.
  FutureWarning,
```

Given the suggestion from the FutureWarning and the [docs](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html), I ran

```
jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True \
--ClearMetadataPreprocessor.enabled=True \
--ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask="{('language_info', 'name')}" \
--ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask="{'kernelspec'}" \
--to=notebook --log-level=ERROR my_notebook.ipynb
```

However, instead of getting my expected output, the notebook has *no* metadata:

```
"metadata": {}
```

**Question**

1. What's going on here? Is it a dependency version issue?
2. How can I get the metadata mask to work without a FutureWarning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is simpler than you trying.
I just tried this and I think it does close to what you want and **importantly, no warning*. (I see the warning when trying your first block in the environment, and so I expect it would be there.):

```bash
jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True \
--ClearMetadataPreprocessor.enabled=True \
--ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask="language_info" \
--ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask="name" \
--ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask="kernelspec" \
--to=notebook --log-level=ERROR index.ipynb
```

I don't think you actually need `"name" there. I think this works, too:

```bash
jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True \
--ClearMetadataPreprocessor.enabled=True \
--ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask="language_info" \
--ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask="kernelspec" \
--to=notebook --log-level=ERROR index.ipynb
```

I will admit I'm not seeing how to submit the tuple so you can leave just the `name` field of the '`language_info`' section.

---

##### In reply to [the comment about the tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76901277/jupyter-nbconvert-function-with-multiple-metadata-masks/76901418?noredirect=1#comment135577638_76901418)

Attempts and results:

```bash
jovyan@jupyter-binder-2dexamples-2drequirements-2dph7y6uqp:~$ jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True \
> --ClearMetadataPreprocessor.enabled=True \
> --ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask= 'language_info', 'name'  \
> --ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask="kernelspec" \
> --to=notebook --log-level=ERROR index.ipynb
usage: jupyter-nbconvert [-h] [--debug] [--show-config] [--show-config-json] [--generate-config] [-y] [--execute] [--allow-errors] [--stdin]
                         [--stdout] [--inplace] [--clear-output] [--no-prompt] [--no-input] [--allow-chromium-download]
                         [--disable-chromium-sandbox] [--show-input] [--embed-images] [--sanitize-html] [--log-level NbConvertApp.log_level]
                         [--config NbConvertApp.config_file] [--to NbConvertApp.export_format] [--template TemplateExporter.template_name]
                         [--template-file TemplateExporter.template_file] [--theme HTMLExporter.theme]
                         [--sanitize_html HTMLExporter.sanitize_html] [--writer NbConvertApp.writer_class]
                         [--post NbConvertApp.postprocessor_class] [--output NbConvertApp.output_base]
                         [--output-dir FilesWriter.build_directory] [--reveal-prefix SlidesExporter.reveal_url_prefix]
                         [--nbformat NotebookExporter.nbformat_version]
                         [extra_args ...]
jupyter-nbconvert: error: unrecognized arguments: index.ipynb
jovyan@jupyter-binder-2dexamples-2drequirements-2dph7y6uqp:~$ 
jovyan@jupyter-binder-2dexamples-2drequirements-2dph7y6uqp:~$ jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True \
> --ClearMetadataPreprocessor.enabled=True \
> --ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask= ('language_info', 'name')  \
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
jovyan@jupyter-binder-2dexamples-2drequirements-2dph7y6uqp:~$ --ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask="kernelspec" \
> --to=notebook --log-level=ERROR index.ipynb
bash: --ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask=kernelspec: command not found
jovyan@jupyter-binder-2dexamples-2drequirements-2dph7y6uqp:~$
```

Do you know the syntax that works for leaving just the `name` entry for `language_info`?

Comment: Thanks @Wayne, actually in the link to the docs above, if you search for the `ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask` configuration, you can see that the default is `Default: {('language_info', 'name')}`. So, I think that's how a tuple is passed in, but I'm unsure why several tuples wouldn't work.

Comment: The tuple 'language_info', 'name' preserves just the 'name' element of 'language_info'

Comment: I thought I tried many times with  `--ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_nb_metadata_mask='language_info', 'name'` and it was giving a syntax error. I'll try again soon and delete this comment and update my answer if I find it working. As for the documentation, I suspect it is still describing the old way to use it. Perhaps(?). Or what the equivalent of such an item would be relative the json of the meta data(?). That was my guess. I think because the issue is due to traitlets changing the documentation is lagging in being updated. I think.

Comment: I tried what you said about, "The tuple 'language_info', 'name' preserves just the 'name' element of 'language_info'." For now, I put my attempts at the bottom of my answer above. Apparently, I am missing something?